# Algorithm to cluster nodes into different trees in a forest

Tags: algorithm

Forest of n-tree is there.

Users will give number of edges to us.

Example :- 1 2, 3 4,    Means 1 and 2, 3 and 4 are  connected

The task is to find which node is part of which tree ?

**My approach** :-

1. Build an array, indexes of array represents node. 
                  `array[i] = j`, Here it represents root of `i` is `j`.

This is the basic approach. Through we can easily know which node is part of which tree.

**Time complexity** O(N^2)

But I need efficient algo, please help me in that.

Comment: how to decide whether two nodes are connected

Comment: By edges, edges will be given by user.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're after [a disjoint-set data structure / the union-find algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure):

> A disjoint-set data structure is a data structure that keeps track of a set of elements partitioned into a number of disjoint (nonoverlapping) subsets. A union–find algorithm is an algorithm that performs two useful operations on such a data structure:
>
> - Find: Determine which subset a particular element is in. This can be used for determining if two elements are in the same subset.
> - Union: Join two subsets into a single subset.
>
> ...
>
> Disjoint-set forests are data structures where each set is represented by a tree data structure, in which each node holds a reference to its parent node (see spaghetti stack).
>
> In a disjoint-set forest, the representative of each set is the root of that set's tree. `Find` follows parent nodes until it reaches the root. `Union` combines two trees into one by attaching the root of one to the root of the other.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is maintaining an adjacency list like for a graph and then do DFS in following manner :-

```
1. find all nodes which do not have incoming edges and form list of roots.
2. do DFS() on each root r and add root[i] = r for each node visited in DFS.
3. So to check if node belongs to a tree you can just check its root.
```

**Time Complexity : -** `O(E)` for finding roots & `O(E)` for DFS hence `O(E)` overall where E is number of edges given

Answer (score 0):

Another method can be :

```
for each node
   parent[node] = -1

for each node
   if(not visited node)
     parent[node]=node
     dfs(node , parent)



dfs(node , parent) :
for each node u connected to node :
if(not visited u)
{
  parent[u] = parent
  dfs(u, parent)
}
```

This gives `O(1) query time` . Takes `O(N) time as each node is visited once  and O(N) space , where N = number of nodes`.